# How to fetch the data for one page at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have the problem to fetch the as per number of rows at a time in jQuery DataTables with Bootstrap. Firstly, my code below fetches whole data from the database and starts the pagination.

But I want data loaded for one page at a time.

My PHP code is:

```php
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th>category</th>
    <th>Location</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($datastat as $row) {

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?> <?php echo $row['mname'];?> <?php echo $row['lname'];?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['category'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['location'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th>category</th>
    <th>Location</th>

    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

My javascript code is:

```js
 $(function() {
    $('#example1').dataTable({
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bLengthChange": true,
       "bFilter": true,
       "bSort": true,
       "pageLength": 10
    });
 });
```

Comment: There are server side pagination demos and server side connectors on the documentation site

Comment: it might be because jquery gets called at the wrong time (rows aren't ready). I would shoot all that data to client- side, and create table rows on with JavaScript or JQuery. Then do your JQuery call. Or do what @charlietfl mentioned.

Comment: @devtye how can rows not be ready...the table is being generated server side. Can't happen

Comment: @charlietfl good call, you are right about it. What do you think is happening?

Comment: nothing is wrong...OP wants less data on page is what i understand

Comment: Ok, it should be right but OP has large amount of data so how to fetch only few row of data at a time as per number of pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement server-side processing in order to retrieve one page at a time from the server, see [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

Luckily DataTables distribution includes PHP class [`ssp.class.php`](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) and [sample code](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php) that makes it fairly easy to use with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gyrocode But its work only for the single table.How can be doing for the id which one primary key of another table.